# Tailwind CSS: The `outline` class does not exist. Yet this is not a custom style, but a framework class

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss

In a new project I get the strange behavior where everything works as intended, except for Outline and related: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/outline-style

The error received:

> The `outline` class does not exist. If you're sure that `outline`
> exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly
> processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be
> used for classes in the same CSS tree.

This is in an `@apply` for a component eg:

```
    .button {
        @apply bg-primary hover:bg-secondary;
    }

    .primary {
        @apply border-2 md:border-none border-primary md:border-transparent;
    }
```

Yet this does not work:

```
    .outline {
        @apply outline outline-2 outline-offset-2 focus:outline-yellow-500;
    }
```

To ensure this is in the same import tree, these are applied in the index.css as part of the components layer:

```
   @layer components {
      ...
   }
```

Any insights into this will be highly appreciated, as none of the references (tailwind documentation, nor their repo bugs, addresses this issue in a workable manner, each example found points to user error. Which may just be the case here, but I am yet to find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply a class to itself. `outline` is already defined (one of the default tailwind classes), you are trying to define and apply it again.

See the error: https://play.tailwindcss.com/cdQLeYFcNH?file=css

> **Error**
>
> `<css input>`: Circular dependency detected when using: `@apply outline`

Use a different custom class. Like `.custom-outline`: https://play.tailwindcss.com/qo8M6Zkj31

Comment: Thank you sir, that oversight on my part seems to be the issue. Truly appreciate the feedback and the solution!